# Join over multiple tables

Tags: sql, sql-server

I want to query the Database (SQL Server 2019 Ent.) of an existing 3rd party application. We have `assets`, their `properties`, and further tables like `managers`, locations,...
The properties are listed in a dedicated table and can contain the value as text or a further `ID` eg. to lookup a managers details. In some cases there are many hundreds of properties per asset. If a property is not set, there is no such record in table `assets`

As an example find a demo-setup here:

https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2016&fiddle=91ebe7c2387fff056c44e927d0e31d54

The goal ist to list each asset inlcluding some specific properties in one record.

| asset | manager | stby_manager | stage |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| saturn-n1 | Carl | David | Production |
| saturn-n2 | David |  | Production |
| mars-n1 | Tim | David |  |

My first idea was to create a temp-table containig the asset and its properties, including the IDs, and then to join the temp-table against the corresponding key tables in a second step. But I'm wodering if there is an easyer way, by joinig the properties and key tables in a whole query?
And btw.; is there a name for this kind of database queries problem? That would have helped me to goolge for it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can definitely have more than one join in the same query, and even use the same table more than once.

```
select a.*, 
    m.firstName as Manager, m2.firstName as Stdby_Manager, 
    p3.property_text as Stage
from assets a
left join properties p on p.asset_id = a.unid and p.property = 'manager'
left join managers m on m.unid = p.property_text

left join properties p2 on p2.asset_id = a.unid and p2.property = 'stby-manager'
left join managers m2 on m2.unid = p2.property_text

left join properties p3 on p3.asset_id = a.unid and p3.property = 'stage'
```

> https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2016&fiddle=d729098bce84b030eed261737179fffa

However, this will never perform as well as it could, because the schema design is using a variant of the flawed Entity-Attribute-Value (EAV) anti-pattern, so you'll never have good foreign key relationships that might have helped this run **MUCH** more efficiently.

Comment: Your query works perfect! Thanks for mentoining the anti-pattern, hope it will help others to avoid this design in an early state.

Answer (score 1):

> is there a name for this kind of database queries problem?

Yes - "pivoting"

SQL Server is not great at pivoting, especially when the results are not numeric. There are some non-intuitive ways to "pivot" related data, but in general I find that pivoting in the *display* layer (website, report, app, etc.) to be much easier and cleaner. in SQL, you have to deal with situations like when related records are missing a pivot column, have multiple values for one attribute, etc.

This can be done in SQL with the `PIVOT` command, but you have to use an aggregation function (typically `MAX`) which looks odd for a non-numeric result. And `PIVOT` requires you to hard-code the resulting columns, so if you add attributes your `PIVOT` query will need to be updated as well.

Or you can use multiple left-joins to turn the attributes into columns, but the columns must be specified there as well.

Both of these can be solved with dynamic SQL, but that reduces performance (typically) and can be bug-prone if you don;t do it right.

Pivoting in apps, on the other hand, typically can be more dynamic, easier to code, etc.

Comment: Thank you for the buzzword! Yes it seems that the software is `pivoting` the data elsewhere than in the DB-layer. Now it makes sense, I had no chance to find th whole query in "SQL Server Profiler"